# Web Api OData v4.0 and Memory Usage/Leak with Castle Windsor

Tags: entity-framework, memory-leaks, asp.net-web-api2, odata, castle-windsor

I have a web project which is configured to provide an OData v 4.0 endpoint and is using the following components:

- ASP.NET Web Api 5.2.2
- Entity Framework 6.1.1
- Owin 5.2.2
- OData 5.3.1

The entire web application is using Windsor container from Castle Project.
The **lifestyle** of my controllers is **per web request** and same applies for all dependencies including **DbContext**.

The IoC is configured as following:

**Owin Startup .cs**

```
WindsorConfig.InitializeContainer(GlobalConfiguration.Configuration);
```

**Configuration.cs**

```
IWindsorContainer container = new WindsorContainer();
container.Install(FromAssembly.This());
container.Register(Component.For<IWindsorContainer>().Instance(container));
config.DependencyResolver = new WindsorDependencyResolver(container);
```

**Installer.cs**

```
container.Register(FromAssembly.This()
    .BasedOn<ODataController>()
    .LifestylePerWebRequest());
container.Register(
    Component
    .For<DbContext>()
    .ImplementedBy<MyContext>()
    .LifestylePerWebRequest());
```

So, an OData controller looks like this:

```
public class PersonsController : ODataController
{
    #region Public Constructors

    public PersonsController(ICommandDispatcher commandDispatcher, DbContext session)
    {
        this.commandDispatcher = commandDispatcher;
        this.session = session;
    }

    public IQueryable<Person> Get()
    {
        return session
            .Set<Person>()
            .AsNoTracking();
    }

    public SingleResult<Person> Get([FromODataUri] Guid key)
    {
        return SingleResult.Create(session
            .Set<Person>()
            .AsNoTracking()
            .Where(x => x.Id == key));
    }

}
```

I am using **Set**.*AsNoTracking()* to avoid extra memory usage from Entity Framework.
Anyway, during time, after 100/150 queries the memory of the app pool keep raising of 1-2 MB and it never gets recycled.

Am I doing something wrong? Maybe Castle is not appropriate for this project and I have to use another IoC container?

Comment: Have you tried long running load testing? 10000 requests and more. What happens then?

Comment: Honestly not, I will create a load test and run it this afternoon. The problem is that the memory used never get released. 
Example, the app starts at 5MB, after running for a while it goes up to 171MB but never goes back to 5MB even if it's inactive for a day or so

Comment: Is it released if you call GC.Collect? I only wander if the GC is fired or not. If the GC is fired and no memory is recollected - then it is a memory leak. I will test you code and experiment.

Comment: It's a web app, how do I call GC.Collect? I can't, it's a web api stack that call it when the controller returns the result. That's why I am using Castle Windsor Lifestyle.PerWebRequest

Comment: Freeing up memory is only performed during garbage collection. See these articles for the further information: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0xy59wtx(v=vs.110).aspx. Your limited testing does not indicate a memory leak.

Comment: Did you see the web.config notes here: https://github.com/castleproject/Windsor/blob/master/docs/lifestyles.md#perwebrequest

Comment: Nope, thanks I will check also the web.config notes